# Why is my type null in React and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function based Child component.

```js
interface ChildProps {
  files: File
}
const Child:React.FC<ChildProps> = ({files}) => {
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState(files);
  const emptyFile = new File([""], " ");
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(files !== null || files !== undefined){
      setFile(files)
    }
    else{
      setFile(emptyFile)
    }
  })
  return (
    <div>
      {file!.name}
    </div>
  )
};
```

I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null` error on `{file!.name}`. But I think it should be emptyFile at least, not null. 
So my questions here,
1. why is it null? I think I take care of `null` case with if statement 
2. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IIRC, useEffect is like componentDidMount, meaning it will happen after the first render. You should put emptyFile inside of your useState to make it work

Comment: I changed it, `const[file, setFile] = React.useState(emptyFile)`, but still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ChildProps interface you are supposed to be getting only valid files here. On the other hand you are trying to check if the `files` property from the parent is valid. So you are most likely passing some null from the parent.
A first error is your condition for checking the files:
if(files !== null || files !== undefined) {}
If your `files` is null then you get a false in first statement, but it's not undefined, so the condition is true.
You should try something like this:

```
interface ChildProps {
  files: File
}

const Child:React.FC<ChildProps> = ({files}) => {
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState(files);
  const emptyFile = new File([""], " ");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(!!files){
      setFile(files)
    }
    else{
      setFile(emptyFile)
    }
  }, [files]);

  return (
    <div>
      {file!.name}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Though the best option would be to just display the files and not to rewrite the prop into your local state. So you can try something like this:

```
interface ChildProps {
  files: File
}
const Child:React.FC<ChildProps> = ({files}) => {

  return (
    <div>
      {files ? files.name : ""}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: It still throws same error. But I like your explanation.

Comment: I just edited the code - there was one typo in the condition. There should be (!!files)

Comment: I never seen using double !!. How does it work? is it same as `not(not)`? Do you have a documentation?

Comment: Yes - that's it double negation. In your case just `if (files) {}` would work the same way. `!!` is used to convert a value to boolean. Here's some page about that https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/3047/double-negation----x-